# Editing an input inside a drag and droppable UL/LI

Tags: javascript

I know this is a fairly specific question, but I'm going for it...

I am using Orangoo's tools to make sortable list.  The form works fine.  See his example:
http://orangoo.com/AJS/examples/sortable_list.html

However, if I want to add inputs or other form elements, I cannot click on the input.  The mouse will be there for a second and then disappear because the ondrag event handling stuff is taking over.

I don't want to remove the drag event from the LI because I do want to reorder the input elements.  Instead, I want a way to keep the focus or ignore the ondrag handling if I click on an input.   I can't figure out how to override the ondrag event though.  If anyone is able to help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering!  I ended up giving in and just turning off the event handler.

```
    <input id="inputId" name="inputName" value="some value" onmousedown="AJS.dnd.removeDragAble(this.parentNode);" onblur="AJS.AEV(this.parentNode, 'mousedown', this.parentNode._start_fn);" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the event from being fired for the drag and drop when the user clicks on an input. Just handle the mousedown event and use event.stopPropagation().

Example:

```
document.getElementById("input1").onmousedown = (function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Great! Now I need to fix handling of blur.

Comment: Let me know if you found a fix!  What I am doing above works, but it sometime causes the starting drag position to be off.  I assume bc of the start fn command.  It just hasn't been important enough to go deal with yet.